# Excel sheet manipulation

Tags: javascript, excel

Here is what i have to do a webpage gives a excel sheet with if we set some conditions and hit get button,then i have to filter for some data on the excel sheet and put it on another excel sheet,like wise have to get data from different excelsheet and put it in a single file.How to do that.

using javascript on page will be better.

Comment: Please can you edit your question for clarity. Must this happen from a webpage on an existing Excel document? Where is the Excel file running?

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear whether the web page contains a *real* Excel spreadsheet, or a HTML/JavaScript representation of it.
The former is only possible (if I remember correctly) only in IE and some ActiveX controls, or maybe with some MS Office showing Excel in browser directly. I am not sure about this because I quit working with MS technologies a while ago.

So, try to view the source of the page and determine which is it.